# Aplicación Node + Express Problema con creación de modulos

Tags: nodejs, express, angular4

Estoy tratando de montar este servidor node que sirve tres cosas:

-- Una aplicación angular que está en el directorio /dist

-- Una apiRest que esta el directorio /api/index y que maneja el middleware

-- Un chat con socket.io que escucha en el mismo puerto 3001 y cuyo código está entre las dos lineas dobles.

Tengo una duda que no sé como resolver:

1. Como puedo separar el código del chat a otro modulo. He intentado ponerlo en fichero distinto pero no sé como pasarle el server que se crea en: const "server = http.createServer(app);"

Un saludo.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const cfg = require('./config/config')
const middleware = require('./middleware');

const app = express();

middleware.useMiddleware(app);

// Configuración de rutas
require('./api/index')(app);

const options = {
        extensions: ['htm', 'html'],
        maxAge: '1d',
        setHeaders: res => res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now())
    }
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist'), options));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/assets'), options));

const server = http.createServer(app);

console.log("==============================================");
const io = socketIO(server);

var onlineUsers = [];

io.on('connection', (socket)=> {

  let query = socket.handshake.query;
  let token = query.token;
  let usu = {
    'id': socket.id,
    'codigo': query.usuCodigo,
    'nome': query.usuNome
  }
  onlineUsers.push(usu);
  io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': onlineUsers });

  socket.on('disconnect', ()=> {

    onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
    let usu = JSON.stringify(onlineUsers);
    io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': usu });
  });

  socket.on('onlineUsers', () => {
    let usu = onlineUsers;
    io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': usu });
  });

  socket.on('add-message', (message) => {
    let mx = JSON.parse(message);
    mx.data = new(Date);
    io.emit('message', { type:'new-message', 'mensaxe': mx });
  });

});
console.log("==============================================");

const porto = cfg.PORTO;
server.listen(porto, ()=> {
  console.log(`Servidor correndo no oo ${porto}`);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución es la siguiente:

1. Tomas el código entre las dos lineas dobles y lo copias en otro modulo. Con la particularidad de que lo pones dentro de una funcion que recibe como argumento el servidor.
2. Haces que el modulo exponga esa funcion.
3. Importas el modulo en el script que crea el servidor y usas la funcion para configurar SocketIO

El nuevo modulo con el código para socket io quedaría asi:

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

module.exports = function(server){
  const io = socketIO(server);

  var onlineUsers = [];

  io.on('connection', (socket)=> {

    let query = socket.handshake.query;
    let token = query.token;
    let usu = {
      'id': socket.id,
      'codigo': query.usuCodigo,
      'nome': query.usuNome
    }
    onlineUsers.push(usu);
    io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': onlineUsers });

    socket.on('disconnect', ()=> {

      onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.indexOf(socket.id), 1);
      let usu = JSON.stringify(onlineUsers);
      io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': usu });
    });

    socket.on('onlineUsers', () => {
      let usu = onlineUsers;
      io.emit('onlineUsers', { type:'onlineUsers', 'usuarios': usu });
    });

    socket.on('add-message', (message) => {
      let mx = JSON.parse(message);
      mx.data = new(Date);
      io.emit('message', { type:'new-message', 'mensaxe': mx });
    });

  });
};
```

Suponiendo que el nuevo modulo se nombre `setup-socket-io.js` y que se encuentre en el mismo directorio que el script usado para crear el servidor este ultimo una vez modificado queda de la siguiente forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const cfg = require('./config/config')
const middleware = require('./middleware');
const setupSocketIO = require('./setup-socket-io');

const app = express();

middleware.useMiddleware(app);

// Configuración de rutas
require('./api/index')(app);

const options = {
        extensions: ['htm', 'html'],
        maxAge: '1d',
        setHeaders: res => res.set('x-timestamp', Date.now())
    }
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist'), options));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/assets'), options));

const server = http.createServer(app);

console.log("==============================================");
setupSocketIO(server);
console.log("==============================================");

const porto = cfg.PORTO;
server.listen(porto, ()=> {
  console.log(`Servidor correndo no oo ${porto}`);
})
```

Comment: Gracias yeiniel, funciona correcto.